# Ionic Native Push Notification (Firebase X) not showing if app is in background

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic-native

I have Ionic Native Push notification enabled on my app, that's through FirebaseX.
My problem is that I get notification if the app is open in foreground but if it's in Background I get nothing.

When I pull up the app, it delivers.

Can anybody shine a light?

Here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FirebaseX } from '@ionic-native/firebase-x/ngx';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';

@Injectable()

export class FCMProvider {
    constructor(
        public firebaseX: FirebaseX,
        public afs: AngularFirestore,
        private platform: Platform,
        private loginService: LoginService
    ) {}

    async getToken() {
        let token;

        if (this.platform.is('android')) {
            token = await this.firebaseX.getToken();
        }

        if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
            const hasPermission = await this.firebaseX.hasPermission();
            if (!hasPermission) {
                await this.firebaseX.grantPermission();
            } else {
                token = await this.firebaseX.getToken();
            }
        }

        console.log(token);

        return this.saveTokenToFirestore(token);
    }

    saveTokenToFirestore(token: string) {
        if (!token) {
            return;
        }

        const devicesRef = this.afs.collection('devices');
        let userOs;
        if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
            userOs = 'ios';
        } else {
            userOs = 'android';
        }
        const docData = {
            token,
            os: userOs,
            userID: this.loginService.getUID()
        };

        return devicesRef.doc(token).set(docData);
    }

    listenToNotifications() {
        return this.firebaseX.onMessageReceived();
    }
}
```

and on my app.component.ts I got this right after `deviceReady`:

```
pushNotification() {
    this.fcProvider.getToken();
    this.fcProvider.listenToNotifications()
      .pipe(
        tap(msg => {
          const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
            message: msg.body,
            duration: 4000
          });
          toast.then(a => a.present());
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
}
```

I'm sending the messages though postman:

```
{
    "to": "e749fugfe793hfhwifh8988799f:...",
    "name": "my_notification",
    "data": {
        "title": "Test",
        "body": "This is just a test notification",
        "notification_foreground": "true",
        "notification_body" : "Notification body",
        "notification_title": "Notification title",
        "forceStart": "1"
    },
    "priority": "high"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling recently with this topic, to hear notifications in the background you have to subscribe to a subscription which you will get in platform.pause (platform is a variable of type Platform from @ionic/angular).

Inside of this subscription you should listen the firebaseX notifications.

I hope my answer has helped you, if you have any questions don't hesitate to ask me.

Comment: Hey @Rafa Amo thank you. Do you mean something like this: this.platform.pause.subscribe(s => this.fcProvider.listenToNotifications().subscribe())

Comment: Yes, that way you should be able to hear messages in the background.